# Canvas create javascript object with methods

Tags: javascript, object, canvas

Hi there i am starting javascript and a find some problems with objects.
I make a nice signature canvas, but now i need to transform to a object with methods...

Here my canvas code:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
const contenu = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 150;
canvas.height = 80;
let signer = false;

function demarrer(e) {
  signer = true;
  dessiner(e);
}

function arreter() {
  signer = false;
  contenu.beginPath();
}

function dessiner(e) {
  if (!signer) return;
  contenu.lineWidth = 2;
  contenu.strokeStyle = "#000";

  contenu.lineTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
  contenu.stroke();
  contenu.beginPath();
  contenu.moveTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
}
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", demarrer);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", arreter);
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", dessiner);
```

```css
#canvas{
border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
```

and here my object 'project'

```js
const canvasElts = {
  canvas: document.querySelector("#canvas"),
  cont: this.canvas.getContext("2d"),
  signer: false,

  dessiner: e => {
    this.canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
      if (!this.signer) return;
      this.cont.lineWidth = 2;
      this.cont.strokeStyle = "#000";

      this.cont.lineTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
      this.cont.stroke();
      this.cont.beginPath();
      this.cont.moveTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
    });
  },

  demarrer: e => {
    this.canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", e => {
      this.signer = true;
      this.dessiner(e);
    });
  },

  arreter: e => {
    this.canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", e => {
      this.signer = false;
      this.cont.beginPath(e);
    });
  },

  eventCanvas: () => {
    this.canvas.width = 150;
    this.canvas.height = 80;
    this.arreter;
    this.demarrer;
    this.dessiner;
  }
};
canvasElts.eventCanvas();
```

```css
#canvas{
border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

the problem is i dont have any console error to help me find the good way...
If some one can help me it would be so great.

thx

Comment: 1. declaring an Object isn't enough, you need to actually call its methods for anything to happen at all 2. your code logic seems off; event handlers are supposed to be added exactly once, not multiple times

Comment: 1. i was calling the object in another js file... i added to the snippet and for the logic i now i am off its because i am here :)

Comment: I guess you need `canvasElts.eventCanvas();` ES6 class example: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/68c1b92d/ And an old school version: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/8ox9e3rf/

Comment: Ok, I need to do a constructor... i was thinking i dont because i need only one canvas. i will try to do the same without watch your exemple again :) A big thx to you.

Comment: You can use your code, but `this.arreter;` for instance does nothing, you, again, need `this.arreter();`

Comment: If i change => Uncaught TypeError: this.arreter is not a function
    at Object.eventCanvas (canvas.js:36)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**first** don't use arrow function `()=>{}` inside the object use normal function instead`function(){}`

**second** call these method

```
/* not */ this.arreter; /*Do this*/ this.arreter();
/* not */ this.demarrer; /*Do this*/ this.demarrer();
/* not */ this.dessiner; /*Do this*/ this.dessiner();
```

there is the correct way of doing that

```
const canvasElts = {
    canvas: document.querySelector("#canvas"),
    cont: this.canvas.getContext("2d"),
    signer: false,

    dessiner: function(e) {
      this.canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
        if (!this.signer) return;
        this.cont.lineWidth = 2;
        this.cont.strokeStyle = "#000";

        this.cont.lineTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
        this.cont.stroke();
        this.cont.beginPath();
        this.cont.moveTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
      });
    },

    demarrer: function(e) {
      this.canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", e => {
        this.signer = true;
        this.dessiner(e);
      });
    },

    arreter: function(e) {
      this.canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", e => {
        this.signer = false;
        this.cont.beginPath(e);
      });
    },

    eventCanvas: function() {
      this.canvas.width = 150;
      this.canvas.height = 80;
      this.arreter();
      this.demarrer();
      this.dessiner();
    }
  };
  canvasElts.eventCanvas();
```

Comment: the name of `()=>{}` is arrow function read about it here [when 'not' to use arrow function](https://dmitripavlutin.com/when-not-to-use-arrow-functions-in-javascript/)